# Why are guides looking like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working on a file in photoshop and every time I drag a guide out I see multiple guides. How can I fix this so only one guide is present? I tried restarting photoshop but the problem persisted.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, like what? What's the problem you're trying to fix? They just look like guides to me.

Comment: So is that supposed to be only a single guide? but ~4 are shown?

Comment: Choose View > Guides > Clear Guides. Then drag out a new guide.. is there more than 1 now?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks Scott. It was the fact that so many appeared when I was just dragging out one that confused me... I realize now that dragging out one activated all previous ones I may have laid there. Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead an mark Scott's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hide guides, then drag out a new guide, all guides are made visible. It appears as though you have merely drug out a few guides for the same area, then perhaps hid guides so you weren't aware they are still there.

Simply clear all the guides by choosing `View > Clear Guides` then drag out a new guide. You should only have one then.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand what is being asked here. If you are dragging one line and you end up with a bunch, it could be because:

- You are hiding the guides, until you drag one and then it shows you all the previous ones (restarting the program won't do anything because the guides are saved in the file itself). SOLUTION: `View > Show > Guides`
- Much less likely but just in case someone else actually has this problem: You might be low on RAM, so the guides are being drawn badly. Restarting should fix it, though.